# Limit ansible output from shell command results list

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts

Team,

how can I avoid this huge output and just get the value I want from every item in the results list?

I just want the item value that is hostname to be shown and only the line from stdout for every host.

```
      - name: "Mount count on GPU Nodes"
        shell: "mount | grep -Ec '/dev/sd.*\\<csi' | awk '{ print $0,\"mounts found on $HOSTNAME\"($0>64? \" that are more than 64.\" : \".\") }'"
        register: mounts_count
        changed_when: false
        failed_when:
        delegate_to: "{{ item }}"
        with_items: "{{ groups['kube-gpu-node'] }}"

      - name: Check if csi related mounts are present on gpu nodes
        assert:
          that:
            - item.stdout is search('64')
          fail_msg: " mounts are present on this node"
          success_msg: "mounts are not present on this node"
        loop: "{{ mounts_count.results }}"
        loop_control:
          label: "{{ item.item }}"
        ignore_errors: yes
```

sample output

```
   TASK [team-services-pre-install-checks : Check if csi related mounts are present on gpu nodes] ***
   Wednesday 18 December 2019  22:47:17 +0000 (0:00:07.012)       0:00:09.110 **** 
   failed: [localhost] (item=node1) => {
       "ansible_loop_var": "item", 
       "assertion": "item.stdout is search('0')", 
       "changed": false, 
       "evaluated_to": false, 
       "item": {
           "ansible_loop_var": "item", 
           "changed": false, 
           "cmd": "mount | grep -Ec '/dev/sd.*\\<csi' | awk '{ print $0,\"mounts found on hostname\"($0>64? \" that are more than 64.\" : \".\") }'", 
           "delta": "0:00:00.102618", 
           "end": "2019-12-18 22:47:12.566399", 
           "failed": false, 
           "invocation": {
               "module_args": {
                   "_raw_params": "mount | grep -Ec '/dev/sd.*\\<csi' | awk '{ print $0,\"mounts found on hostname\"($0>64? \" that are more than 64.\" : \".\") }'", 
                   "_uses_shell": true, 
                   "argv": null, 
                   "chdir": null, 
                   "creates": null, 
                   "executable": null, 
                   "removes": null, 
                   "stdin": null, 
                   "stdin_add_newline": true, 
                   "strip_empty_ends": true, 
                   "warn": true
               }
           }, 
           "item": "node1", 
           "rc": 0, 
           "start": "2019-12-18 22:47:12.463781", 
           "stderr": "", 
           "stderr_lines": [], 
           "stdout": "1 mounts found on hostname.", 
           "stdout_lines": [
               "1 mounts found on hostname."
           ]
       }, 
       "msg": " mounts are present on this node"
   }
ok: [localhost] => (item=node2) => {
       "ansible_loop_var": "item", 
       "changed": false, 
       "item": {
           "ansible_loop_var": "item", 
           "changed": false, 
           "cmd": "mount | grep -Ec '/dev/sd.*\\<csi' | awk '{ print $0,\"mounts found on hostname\"($0>64? \" that are more than 64.\" : \".\") }'", 
           "delta": "0:00:00.109244", 
           "end": "2019-12-18 22:47:14.303305", 
           "failed": false, 
           "invocation": {
               "module_args": {
                   "_raw_params": "mount | grep -Ec '/dev/sd.*\\<csi' | awk '{ print $0,\"mounts found on hostname\"($0>64? \" that are more than 64.\" : \".\") }'", 
                   "_uses_shell": true, 
                   "argv": null, 
                   "chdir": null, 
                   "creates": null, 
                   "executable": null, 
                   "removes": null, 
                   "stdin": null, 
                   "stdin_add_newline": true, 
                   "strip_empty_ends": true, 
                   "warn": true
               }
           }, 
           "item": "node2", 
           "rc": 0, 
           "start": "2019-12-18 22:47:14.194061", 
           "stderr": "", 
           "stderr_lines": [], 
           "stdout": "0 mounts found on hostname.", 
           "stdout_lines": [
               "0 mounts found on hostname."
           ]
       }, 
       "msg": "mounts are not present on this node"
   }
```

expected output: below is just a manual sample i made but any thing that shows hostname and stdout_line is good enough.

```
"item": "node1"
0 mounts found on hostname.

"item": "node2"
0 mounts found on hostname.
```

Answer (score 0):

Ansible isn't really designed to produce "nice" output on the console. If you want information produced in a specific format, you are better off generating a file from a template.

That said, the `assert` module is designed primarily as a debugging tool and generates verbose output.  I think you could get the behavior you want using the `fail` module instead:

```
      - name: Check if csi related mounts are present on gpu nodes
        fail:
          msg: " mounts are present on this node"
        when: item.stdout is not search('64')
        loop: "{{ mounts_count.results }}"
        loop_control:
          label: "{{ item.item }}"
        ignore_errors: yes
```

This will simply "skip" items for which the `when` condition is false.

Comment: I want to print both success and failure messages. basically its reporting task of how many mounts are found. 0, 64, 64+

Comment: The Ansible console output is customizable to some extent. I added an answer with examples @AhmFM

Answer (score 0):

A little bit late to the party, but still there is a solution.

While [@larsks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/147356/larsks)'s statement about nice output is correct by default, we have multiple ways to improve that.

## Use only minimal data in loops

We don't need the whole dictionary to process in a loop - [`ansible.builtin.keep_keys()`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/utils/keep_keys_filter.html) filter allows us to select only the part of data that's enough:

```yaml
    - name: Check if csi related mounts are present on gpu nodes
      assert:
        that:
          - item.stdout is search('64')
        fail_msg: " mounts are present on this node"
        success_msg: "mounts are not present on this node"
      loop: "{{ mounts_count.results | ansible.utils.keep_keys(['item', 'stdout']) }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.item }}"
      ignore_errors: yes
```

This produces:

```py
TASK [Check if csi related mounts are present on gpu nodes (by the OP)] ***********************************************************************************************************************
failed: [localhost] (item=localhost) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "assertion": "item.stdout is not search('6')",
    "changed": false,
    "evaluated_to": false,
    "item": {
        "item": "localhost",
        "stdout": "7 mounts found on localhost that are more than 6."
    },
    "msg": " mounts are present on this node"
}
...ignoring
```

## Use Ansible modules instead of shell scripts whenever possible

### Example without assertions

There is no need to use shell scripts because Ansible [gathers facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html) that include the mounts of the nodes, so you can process them to report (make sure you have `gather_facts: true` on the play):

```yaml
    - name: Check if csi related mounts are present on gpu nodes
      debug:
        msg: "{{ ansible_facts['ansible_mounts'] | length }} mounts found on {{ inventory_hostname }}"
      failed_when: ansible_facts['ansible_mounts'] | length != 64
```

This produces:

```py
TASK [List the number of mounts] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [test1] => {
    "msg": "64 mounts found on test1"
}
fatal: [test2]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "0 mounts found on test2"
}
fatal: [test3]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "128 mounts found on test3"
```

Note that it's true for Linux systems and won't work on Mac OS.

### Example with assertions

Also, we can return to `assert` module but it would be a little more verbose than that:

```yaml
    - name: Check if csi related mounts are present on gpu nodes (using assert module, quiet = false)
      vars:
        message: "{{ ansible_facts['ansible_mounts'] | length }} mounts are present on this node"
      assert:
        that:
          - ansible_facts['ansible_mounts'] | length != 64
        fail_msg: "{{ message }}"
        success_msg: "{{ message }}"
```

Which produces:

```py
TASK [Check if csi related mounts are present on gpu nodes (using assert module, quiet = false)] **********************************************************************************************
fatal: [test1]: FAILED! => {
    "assertion": "ansible_facts['ansible_mounts'] | length != 64",
    "changed": false,
    "evaluated_to": false,
    "msg": "64 mounts are present on this node"
}
ok: [test2] => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "0 mounts are present on this node"
}
ok: [test3] => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "128 mounts are present on this node"
}
```

That verbosity could be decreased by using `quiet: true`:

```yaml
    - name: Check if csi related mounts are present on gpu nodes (using assert module, quiet = true)
      vars:
        message: "{{ ansible_facts['ansible_mounts'] | length }} mounts are present on this node"
      assert:
        that:
          - ansible_facts['ansible_mounts'] | length != 64
        fail_msg: "{{ message }}"
        success_msg: "{{ message }}"
        quiet: true
```

Which produces the output only for failing conditions, which is useful in reports:

```py
TASK [Check if csi related mounts are present on gpu nodes (using assert module, quiet = true)] ***********************************************************************************************************
ok: [test1]
fatal: [test2]: FAILED! => {"assertion": "ansible_facts['ansible_mounts'] | length == 64", "changed": false, "evaluated_to": false, "msg": "0 mounts are present on this node"}
fatal: [test3]: FAILED! => {"assertion": "ansible_facts['ansible_mounts'] | length == 64", "changed": false, "evaluated_to": false, "msg": "128 mounts are present on this node"}
```

## Control Ansible log output using callback plugin settings

### Prettify the default output

Even the [`default`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/default_callback.html) callback is quite flexible. For example, you can leverage `callback_result_format` and `callback_format_pretty` parameters which can help you to get rid of excessive symbols brought by JSON and/or fix the indentation so that the log gets much more readable. You can find the combination that suits you the most. Consider the following example `ansible.cfg`:

```ini
[defaults]
callback_result_format = yaml
; callback_format_pretty is true by default when callback_result_format = yaml
```

Without any modification to the playbook, the output formatting will be improved:

```py
TASK [Check if csi related mounts are present on gpu nodes (using debug module)] **************************************************************************************************************
ok: [test1] => 
    msg: 64 mounts found on test1
fatal: [test2]: FAILED! => 
    msg: 0 mounts found on test2
fatal: [test3]: FAILED! => 
    msg: 128 mounts found on test3

TASK [Check if csi related mounts are present on gpu nodes (using assert module, quiet = false)] **********************************************************************************************
ok: [test1] => 
    changed: false
    msg: 64 mounts are present on this node
fatal: [test2]: FAILED! => 
    assertion: ansible_facts['ansible_mounts'] | length == 64
    changed: false
    evaluated_to: false
    msg: 0 mounts are present on this node
fatal: [test3]: FAILED! => 
    assertion: ansible_facts['ansible_mounts'] | length == 64
    changed: false
    evaluated_to: false
    msg: 128 mounts are present on this node

TASK [Check if csi related mounts are present on gpu nodes (using assert module, quiet = true)] ***********************************************************************************************
ok: [test1]
fatal: [test2]: FAILED! => 
    assertion: ansible_facts['ansible_mounts'] | length == 64
    changed: false
    evaluated_to: false
    msg: 0 mounts are present on this node
fatal: [test3]: FAILED! => 
    assertion: ansible_facts['ansible_mounts'] | length == 64
    changed: false
    evaluated_to: false
    msg: 128 mounts are present on this node
```

### Use custom stats

Finally, Ansible provides [`show_custom_stats`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/default_callback.html#parameter-show_custom_stats) callback parameter to use custom stats in the play recap. They could be set by [`set_stats`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/set_stats_module.html) module:

```
; ansible.cfg
[defaults]
callback_result_format = yaml
callback_format_pretty = true
show_custom_stats = true
```

```yaml
# playbook.yaml
- name: Get the mount details using Ansible facts
  hosts: kube_gpu_node
  gather_facts: true
  tasks:
    - name: Set stats for mounts
      set_stats:
        data:
          number_of_mounts: "{{ ansible_facts['ansible_mounts'] | length }}"
        per_host: true
    
    - name: Check if csi related mounts are present on gpu nodes (using debug module)
      debug:
        msg: "{{ ansible_facts['ansible_mounts'] | length }} mounts found on {{ inventory_hostname }}"
      failed_when: ansible_facts['ansible_mounts'] | length != 64
```

Note that:

- `kube-gpu-node` is not a valid group name, one should use underscores instead of hyphens
- `failed_when` should not be used with `set_stats` because even with `ignore_errors: true` it will stop on the first error and the stats will not be set for other hosts. So to have a proper play recap, you'll need either a `debug` with `failed_when` condition, or an `assert`.

The output will be something like that:

```py
PLAY [Get the mount details using Ansible facts] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [test3]
ok: [test2]
ok: [test1]

TASK [Set stats for mounts] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [test1]
ok: [test2]
ok: [test3]

TASK [Check if csi related mounts are present on gpu nodes (using assert module, quiet = false)] **********************************************************************************************************
ok: [test1] => 
    changed: false
    msg: 64 mounts are present on this node
fatal: [test2]: FAILED! => 
    assertion: number_of_mounts | int == 64
    changed: false
    evaluated_to: false
    msg: 0 mounts are present on this node
fatal: [test3]: FAILED! => 
    assertion: number_of_mounts | int == 64
    changed: false
    evaluated_to: false
    msg: 128 mounts are present on this node

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
test1                      : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
test2                      : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
test3                      : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   


CUSTOM STATS: *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
        test1:  number_of_mounts: 64
        test2:  number_of_mounts: 0
        test3:  number_of_mounts: 128
```